# Pandas dataframe - retrieve specific value from a column based on the most recent value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve the most recent value (above the current row) of column B when the value of Column A is "OPEN" and then populate this value on the current row where Column A value is "CLOSE" The following code is almost working but it retrieving the most recent value (above the current row) when Column A is "CLOSE" instead of "OPEN. The following is the code I am using:

```
data.loc[(data['A'] == "CLOSE"), 'C'] = data.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.shift()). The output of the table is as below.
```

[image]

However, the value of Column C for the first instance when Column A = "CLOSE" should be "23120". For the next instance when Column A = "CLOSE, the value of Column C should be 23330 and so on.

Any ideas on how I can fix this code? Thank you in advance.

```
data.loc[(data['A'] == "CLOSE"), 'C'] = data.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.shift()). The output of the table is as below.
```

[image]

However, the value of Column C for the first instance when Column A = "CLOSE" should be "23120". For the next instance when Column A = "CLOSE, the value of Column C should be 23330 and so on.

Any ideas on how I can fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map()` to look up the corresponding value of column B when column A is 'open'.

```
data.loc[data['A'] == "CLOSE", 'C'] = data.loc[data['A'] == "CLOSE", 'A'].map(data.loc[data['A'] == "OPEN", 'B'])
```

Comment: thank you. What If I have a few other rows in the middle where the values of column was something else or even blank. I'd still want to be able to retrieved the row with "OPEN" but only look on the rows above the current row and not below

Comment: You mean the values in column "A" being blank or values in column "B"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **shift**:

```
data['C'] = data['B'].shift()
data.loc[data['A'] == "OPEN", 'C']=''
```

Comment: thank you. What If I have a few other rows in the middle where the values of column was something else or even blank. I'd still want to be able to retrieved the row with "OPEN" but only look on the rows above the current row and not below